# Trigger Activiti workflow for task sitting in ReceiveTask looping

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

I have an Activiti workflow that contains a ReceiveTask where I'm grouping tasks. I have a Listener that triggers on the event start of the ReceiveTask where I check the property of the newly added task to see if others with the same properties are in the ReceiveTask. If yes, then I want to trigger them all to move to the next step.

```
<receiveTask id="IssuePost" name="Issue Post">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:executionListener event="start" delegateExpression="${IssuePost}"></activiti:executionListener>
  </extensionElements>
</receiveTask>
```

My Java Listener class IssuePost gets called when the task moves to the ReceiveTask just fine. I can get the list of other tasks sitting in that ReceiveTask. I'm having a problem triggering the tasks to move to the next step in the workflow. I get caught in a loop when calling "signal" on the tasks. The IssuePost listener keeps on getting triggered in an infinite loop until Alfresco/Activiti gives up and throws an exception.

```
List<NodeRef> siblingNodes = searchService.selectNodes( parent, xpath, null, namespacePrefixResolver, false );
if( siblingNodes.size() == batchCount )
{
    for( int i=0; i < siblingNodes.size(); i++ )
    {
        List<WorkflowInstance> workflows = workflowService.getWorkflowsForContent( siblingNodes.get( i ), true );
        // this line causes the loop.
        workflowService.signal( workflows.get(0).getId(), null );
```

How can I signal the tasks in the ReceiveTask to move to the next step in the workflow without triggering my listener? There's only one flow out of the ReceiveTask to the next step in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the **InvitationServiceImpl** I see the following useful snippet:

```
    List<WorkflowTask> tasks = workflowService.getTasksForWorkflowPath(startTask.getPath().getId());
    if(tasks.size()==1)
    {
        WorkflowTask task = tasks.get(0);
        if(taskTypeMatches(task, taskTypes))
        {
            if(properties != null)
            {
                workflowService.updateTask(task.getId(), properties, null, null);
            }
            workflowService.endTask(task.getId(), transition);
            return;
        }
    }
```

So you need to have the task itself to update or end or even start.

Or maybe in your case, lookup the next transition which is after start and signal that one instead of null.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what 'endTask' actually does? The javadoc comments are a little lacking. I shouldn't need to fill in the next transition since there is only one path out of the current workflow node. Seems like I'll need to run the whole Alfresco service in debug just to see what's going on. It seems to me that what I'm trying to accomplish is a basic operation.

Comment: Yep I know, and has become a bit harder since JBPM. In that you could just get the current task from the excecution and end it.
End just means like completing the task (clicking on Next UI) so giving the transition is more when you've got multiple transitions. So I think if you implement the above code, which is default code it should work.

Comment: It seems like an Activit transaction problem. The task is within a transaction as it gets moved to my Receive Task in the workflow. Calling "signal" somehow breaks that.

Comment: I don't really understand, have you tried endTask? And if yes it still triggers your listener?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. If I call endTask, it... ends the task! But I need to move the task to the next step within the listener instance, and it won't do that if I call endTask. I'm rewriting my workflow to hopefully get around this.

Comment: That's strange, endTask is ending the current task and not the workflow. So if you've got a process going it will still go through. So like you're saying you need to make some modification to your current flow